# Browser waiting for ajax to finish mvc ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an application written in MVC3.  I have a page that loads a large graph by asynchronously with ajax:

```
var graphRequest;

function ReloadGraph() {

        if ($('#graph').length < 1) {

        return;


    var graphData;

    // get the graph data
    graphData = GetGraphData();

}

graphRequest = $.ajax({
        cache: true,
        type: 'POST',
        data: { selectedReportID: selectedReportID, selectedUnit: unit, price: price },
        url: "/Dashboard/GetGraphData",
        async: true,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
                   RenderGraph(result);
});
```

When the page loads the graph looks to render and in the success function will render a flot chart.

The issue I am having is, when the user lands on the dashboard they are selecting another page (Stats) via the navigation.  This immediately directs the user to another page.  Then if I click back to the dashboard the graph tries to render again. However the next time I click on the Stats link the page will not load until the ajax is completed!

Has anyone seen this before? If I remove the ajax request then the system works fine so the ajax I believe is the problem.  I have further tried to abort the request as follows:

```
$('#nav a').live('click', function () {
    console.log("aborting");
    graphRequest.abort();
});
```

But with no prevail.  Any suggestions or direction would be great.

Thanks